# $output is error or not

Tags: php, linux

I have a simple PHP program which creates tar. In success case it outputs file name and in failure case output is error message.

My question is how to apply condition for checking whether it is an error or not.

like:

```
If ($output == error)
    {
    do something....     
   }
else{
  do something....
}
```

my php code is below:

```
<?php

$output = shell_exec("tar cvzf /var/www/html/abhishek/abhi.tar.gz -C /var/www/html/abhishek/ abhi.pdf 2>&1");

echo $output;

?>
```

NOTE: my file name is dynamic.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look to the PHP class PharData: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UNIX utility typically ends with an exit status. This exit status is `0` for success or anything else to indicate an error (different numbers for different errors). [`exec`](http://php.net/exec) instead of `shell_exec` lets you capture that code:

```
$lastLine = exec("tar ...", $output, $exitCode);

if ($exitCode == 0) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

Comment: why we need `$output` here?

Comment: Because you may want to capture the whole output, the return value is just the last line. You also need to supply an argument if you want to supply the `$exitCode` argument after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file name , then you can check whether the file exists using `file_exists`. If, it exists, then its success & if it didn't, its error

Comment: but file name is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec utility. Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Hope this might help you

Thanks